# Will await calls be performed in parallel when looped over?

Tags: javascript, rest, promise, fetch, es6-promise

Suppose we have a look like this:

```
documents.forEach(url=>{
     await fetch(url).
     then(
        document=>
        console.log(document);
}
```

Will this load all the documents in parallel, or will the documents be loaded in serial?

In other words we could push the `fetch` promises into an array and then call `Promise.all` on that array which will execute all the promises in parallel.

IIUC there is no difference really except the `Promise.all` will fail on the first failure of a `fetch` request.

Comment: Yes, in parallel.

Comment: Thanks  - I thought so just wanted to double check.

Comment: @damian no and no. JS is not "single threaded" and "technically serial" is ... *vague*

Comment: This code cannot work. `await` can only occur in an `async` function.

Comment: Even if you put async into the function (which you must since you're using await), this won't run in parallel because the whole point of await is to wait for a promise to not just return, but either resolve or reject.

Comment: @alex067 no, you seem to missunderstand how async / await work ...

Comment: @alex067 not *synchronously*.

Comment: This will definitely not run in parallal @JonasWilms. If you want to run multiple async in parallel, you have to map over each promise and use promise.all()

Comment: @alex067 No, you don't have to use `map` and you don't have to use `Promise.all`. Just calling all the async functions at once is enough. You only need `Promise.all` if you want to wait for all the results (which you usually *should*, but it's not a necessity).

Comment: @Bergi interesting, thanks for the clarification

Comment: To those who are discussing "parallel": this is probably just a matter of definition. JS does not run two lines of JS code in parallel, but there is non-JS code triggered by JS, which *does* run in parallel. In this case that is the process dealing with waiting for the HTTP response and notifying its arrival to the JS layer. All those triggered by JS can (and will often) run in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the callback function is declared as `async`, then `await` can be used:

```
documents.forEach(async url => {
     await fetch(url).then(console.log);
}
```

The sequence of execution is then as follows:

1. The `forEach` method is executed.
2. This includes calling the callback for each `url`, which happens one after the other
3. One execution of the callback will call `fetch`, which launches the HTTP request and returns immediately with a promise. In the background the non-JavaScript, lower-level API polls for the HTTP response to come in. Only that background part happens in parallel with the steps described here.
4. The `then` method is executed and the callback passed to it is registered. The `then` method immediately returns a promise
5. The `await` kicks in: the callback function's execution context is saved and it exits, returning a promise which this code ignores.
6. The next iteration takes place, repeating from step 3.
7. The `forEach` method ends. At this stage there are several non-JavaScript threads polling for HTTP responses, and there are several JS execution contexts pending for later execution.
8. In some unpredictable order (depending on the response time of the server giving the response), the `fetch` API resolves the promise that it had returned, and puts a message in the Promise Job Queue to indicate that.
9. The JavaScript event loop detects the event and proceeds with the execution of the callback registered in step 4 (the `then` callback), outputting to the console. The promise that was returned by the `then` method is resolved, which puts a new message in the Promise Job Queue.
10. The message is pulled from the queue and this will restore the corresponding execution context of the `forEach` callback. The execution continues after the `await`, and as there is nothing more to execute, the promise returned in step 5 is resolved (but no-one listens to that)
11. JavaScript monitors the event queue for more such work, and will at some point repeat at step 8.

No JavaScript code executes in parallel with JavaScript here, but the `fetch` API relies on non-JavaScript code, reaching "down" into Operating System functions, which *do* run in parallel with JavaScript code (and other OS functions).

Also note that the code is very similar to this non-`async/await` variant:

```
documents.forEach(url =>
     fetch(url).then(console.log)
);
```

...because this callback *also* returns a promise. Except for the "saving execution context" part, which is not taking place here, the execution plan is quite similar.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation!  I added an elaboration to the end of my question.  Does that seem correct to you?

Comment: Just a clarification: `Promise.all` does not execute promises. Promises do not execute either. They are objects. What executes is some asynchronous low-level process underlying an asynchronous API (like `fetch`), which is already happening at the moment you execute `Promise.all`. `Promise.all` only creates yet another promise whose status is made dependent on the statuses of the promises passed to it. `Promise.all` does not influence the order of execution, nor the promises that are given to it.

Comment: Good clarification!  I really meant "Run/Listen for completion of promise resolution or error".  In this case I'm just using Angular http to fetch documents and I've wrapped the calls inside my own `fetch` function. I assume then that based on what you are saying that there is no difference between using `Promise.all` to wait for all promises to complete or one to fail, or just using await with a catch block that will handle error per promise as far as execution time goes?

Comment: As long as you make sure to create all involved promises as soon as possible, yes. It is another story when you would create the second promise only after the first one resolves, etc, which is what you get with `for (url of documents) { await fetch(url) }`.

Comment: So in other words if we use `http.get` to get a Promise, then push that promise onto an array, and then do that again for all documents, and then call `Promise.all(arr).then(result=>{}); .... that will have the same execution time as the `await` version in the question?

Comment: Ah - OK - I think I got it now - You are saying that the execution will be serial because each `await fetch` execution will block until the document is received, and then the next loop iteration will occur?

Comment: Yes to that last comment. About your one-but-last comment: the addition of `Promise.all` does not influence that, but it allows you to *know* when you have all responses. You would *not* know with the code in your question, where the `forEach` loop will finish immediately, but you cannot proceed with any conclusion yet. Without `Promise.all` you would for instance increment a counter in the `then` callback and see when you have them all: `console.log(url); if (++count == documents.length) console.log("Got them all");`

Comment: Ok - I think I got it now - So I would have to remove the `await` and get each promise, push that promise onto an array, pass that array to `Promise.all` and then all the `http` requests should execute in parallel, and the `console.log` will execute as the documents come in?

Comment: Also IIUC we can do `Promise.all(arr).then(result=>console.log("All promises executed correctly).catch(e=>console.log("An error occurred");`

Comment: I am [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203621/discussion-between-ole-and-trincot)